# Variation Description

Tags: woocommerce, echo, variant, field-description

Hi I would like to ask how to Echo the variation product description. I would need to echo it depending on variant chosen. I have a working code to echo short descriptin of the curent product like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woo_show_excerpt_shop_page_rz', 80 );
function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page_rz() {
        global $product;
        echo $product->post->post_excerpt;
}
```

I would need something similar with current variant description.